# Appending a property to an object in Jquery dot notation

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to add a property to an object, but Dot notation can't handle a string.

my object:

```
var lists = {
"Cars":{"Ford":false,"Ferarri":false},
"Names":{"John":true,"Harry":false},
"Homework":{"Maths":true,"Science":false,"History":true,"English":true}
}
```

Adding a property:

```
function add_item() {
var input = "Alfa Romeo";
var command = eval('lists.Cars.' +  input + '=false');
}
```

How can I do this using Bracket Notation seeing as it's a 2D object?

Comment: Didn't know you could combine both notations, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for eval.. and `blah` is undefined in your example.

```
var lists = {
  "Cars":{"Ford":false,"Ferarri":false},
  "Names":{"John":true,"Harry":false},
  "Homework":{"Maths":true,"Science":false,"History":true,"English":true}
} 

function add_item(key, value) {
  lists.Cars[key] = value;
}

add_item('Alfa Romeo', true);

console.log(lists);
```